# Show linearity using additivity and continuity at zero

Tags: continuity, functional-equations

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous at $0$ and $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$ for all $x, y$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Show that there is a real number $c$ such that $f(x) = cx$.

I'm not sure about how to do show this, I can tell that $f(0) = 0$ and that from continuity at $0$ we get $|f(x)| < \epsilon$ for $x$ in some delta neighborhood of $0$. Can anyone help me with this please.

**Edit:** please note that the function is only continuous at $0$ so Cauchy functional equation properties can't be used here.

Comment: Look at the properties near the top of the answer more carefully.

Comment: @epimorphic so sorry I just saw it. Thanks a lot for the help